# Converting Jquery to Javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following Jquery Code

```
(function ($) {
    $('.afc_close_content').click(function() {          
        var afc_content_id = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
        $('#'+afc_content_id).hide();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I have change it JavaScript

```
(function () {
    document.getElementByClassName("afc_close_content").click(function() {          
        let afc_content_id = this.closest('div').attr('id');
        $('#'+afc_content_id).style.display = "none";
    });
});
```

But the above code does not work

Where am I wrong?

**URL:** https://www.wordpress4.guru99.com/what-is-sap.html

Comment: See also [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](/q/10693845/4642212). Neither an `HTMLCollection` nor a `NodeList` has a `click` method. This reminds me of the article [jQuery considered harmful](//lea.verou.me/2015/04/jquery-considered-harmful/).

Comment: Use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple event listeners — it’s more maintainable, and applies to dynamically added elements. E.g., use an [event argument](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](/q/1687296/4642212).

Comment: You have at least four distinct problems here (not counting the bit where you're still calling the jQuery function). Focus on one at a time.

Comment: Please see [something in my website doesn't work - can I just paste a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score -1):

1. You can loop over the elements.
2. Use `addEventListener` instead of the jQuery `.click` method.
3. Use `document.querySelectorAll`, `document.querySelector`, or `document.getElementById` instead of the jQuery function.

```
(function() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".afc_close_content").forEach(el => 
      el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        let afc_content_id = this.closest('div').id;
        document.getElementById(afc_content_id).style.display = 'none';
      })
    );
});
```

Comment: To point 1: no, you don’t _need_ to loop over the elements. You can use the DOM event propagation model to your advantage instead.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I agree that event delegation can be used instead, but this is just a direct rewriting of the jQuery code in the original post.